# VB.net Cross-Thread

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar, multithreading

I have a cmd command that needs to be executed, when the command starts it starts to fill a progressbar. When the cmd command is done the progressbar needs to fill up to 100.

This is the code i use, but it gives me an error when the progressbar.Value = 100 comes up.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim teller As Integer

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TimerProgressbar.Tick
    teller += 1
    ProgressBar1.Value = teller

    If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
        TimerProgressbar.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

This are the tow commands in another private sub where the app is crashing on

```
ProgressBar1.Value = 100
    TimerProgressbar.Stop()
```

When i debug it and i try it out it crashes on

```
ProgressBar1.Value = 100
```

But when i build it under Windows 7 it runs fine without crashing, however a few people reported me it crashes on there Windows xp system.

VB gives me a suggestions about Cross Thread, but i don't know how i could make it work with this.

Comment: Nothing you're showing is "cross thread" - Windows.Forms.Timer's Tick event is on the UI thread.  What is the error you are actually receiving?

Comment: Forgot something, i start the progress bar with a button outside the

ProgressBar1.Value = 100
    TimerProgressbar.Stop()

Im indeed getting the IllegalOperationException error. with a link to a cross thread page.

Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button.Click
TimerProgressbar.Start()
End Sub

Comment: btw it gives IllegalOperationException

Answer (score 0):

You can only access (with one exception) a Window's (or anything tied to Window) properties and methods from the thread that created that Window.

But WinForms includes support for this with the `Invoke` (and `BeginInvoke`) methods to perform a cross thread call, with the `InvokeRequired` property.

If `InvokeRequired` is true, then you need to use `Invoke` to cross threads. To do this wrap your code that manipulates the control in its own method, and either call directly, or via `Invoke`. (To perform the operation cross threads asynchronously use `BeginInvoke` instead.) Something like:

```
Private Sub IncrementProgress()
    teller += 1
    ProgressBar1.Value = teller

    If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
        TimerProgressbar.Stop()
    End If
End Sub      

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TimerProgressbar.Tick
  if ProgressBar1.RequiredInvoke Then
    ProgressBar1.Invoke(IncrementProgress)
  Else
    IncrementProgress
  End If
End Sub
```